# PHP include .tpl file without smart framework

Tags: php, html

ok so I use a PHP framework called lemonade it allows me to instead of creating PHP files for each link e.g.

http://example.com/social.php
The code allows me to call functions in our core php script which loads all the important PHP stuff and then i use .tpl files (not i just name them that i don't use the smarty framework - I name them .tpl because they are a template file)

But i seem to be having issues with one page
it sometimes loads fully and other times it's like it dies half way from loading the part that does not show is the sign up section

I have included the full code here

```
<div class="background">
<div class="contentarea">
    <div class="Grid-cell u-size4of4 no-bg">
        <div class="banner">
            <div class="float_bottom cnetertext">
               <center> <span class="slogen" align="center"><?=$lang["frontpage"]["banner"][0];?>
                <br>
                <?=$lang["frontpage"]["banner"][1];?></span>
               </center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="Grid-cell u-size3of4" style="float:left;">
        <div class="internal">
           texthere
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="//<?=siteurl;?>/template/main/js/registervalidation.js"></script>
    <div class="Grid-cell u-size3of4">
        <div class="internal">
            <h1 class="hevetics">Sign up</h1>
            <p class="signuptext">It's free and always will be.</p>
            <form action="/signup" name="register" method="post" class="ipetsignup" enctype="multipart/form-data"  onsubmit="return registervalidation();">
                <label class="half">
                    <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="<?=$lang["form"]["signup"]["FirstName"];?>" onchange="name();" required/>
                </label>
                <label class="half" style="float:right; margin-right:2%;">
                    <input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" onchange="name();" placeholder="<?=$lang["form"]["signup"]["LastName"];?>" required >
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input id="emailone" type="email" name="email" placeholder="<?=$lang["form"]["signup"]["email"];?>" onchange="checkemails();" required >
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input id="emailtwo" type="email" name="checkemail" placeholder="<?=$lang["form"]["signup"]["reemail"];?>"  onchange="checkemailtwo();" required>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="<?=$lang["form"]["signup"]["newpassword"];?>" required>
                </label>
                <label class="h1">Birthday</label>
                <label class="select">
                    <select name="day">
                        <option value="00" disabled selected>Day</option>
                        <?php
                        for($i=1;$i<=31; $i++)
                        {
                           $n = sprintf("%02s", $i);
                           echo '<option value="'.$n.'">'.$n.'</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                 </label>
                 <label class="select">
                 <select name="month">
                        <option value="00" disabled selected>Month</option>
                        <?php
                        for($i=1;$i<=12; $i++)
                        {
                           $n = sprintf("%02s", $i);
                           echo '<option value="'.$n.'">'.date("F",strtotime('01.'.$n.'.2001')).'</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                 </label>
                 <label  class="select">
                    <select name="year">
                        <option value="00" disabled selected>Year</option>
                        <?php
                            $year = date("Y");
                        for($i=$year-99;$i<=$year; $i++)
                        {

                           echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </label>

                <label>
                     <input id="signup" type="submit" class="button" value="Sign up"> 
                </label>    
            </form>
        </div>    
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this line:

```
<script src="//<?=siteurl;?>/template/main/js/registervalidation.js"></script>
```

It seems that you forgot to use `$` before variable name - it should be probably `$siteurl` and the other thing is if `$siteurl` starts with `http://`. If yes, this line probably should look like:

```
<script src="<?= $siteurl ?>/template/main/js/registervalidation.js"></script>
```

Comment: but would that stop the script for continuing?

Comment: and no that does not need a $ in front as it is a define

Comment: If the path is incorrect it may stop displaying the rest of the page so make sure this file exists. Also for `define` you should rather use uppercase notation

Comment: Thank you for that advice with define - first time i heard about that - will change it for our next version the link is correct

Comment: could it be the include / require part that i use in my PHP code? I correctly use require

Comment: Hard to say. You should check if you don't use other loops using `$i` variable. If you use and inside loop you include this file or other loops using `$i` variable it can cause a problem. However it's hard to say if you haven't included full code and it's impossible to test the whole script.